# External images in .rdlc data reports for winforms

Tags: winforms, c#-2.0, rdlc

I searched Google for days to show images on .rdlc datareports but still not found a solution.
I have set:
reportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
Image properties to "External" and have set parameters value to the value property.

```
 ReportParameter Path;
        Path = new ReportParameter("Path", "C:\\Test\\579569.png");
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { Path });
```

But still i get a broken image. Is there something i am missing.I am trying this in WinForms.
I know this question is asked by others..but i didn't get the result that i wanted.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

@Praveen is right. I used `Server.MapPath` to get the physical path of the image:

```
"file:///" + Server.MapPath("~/images/nokia.jpg")
```

and then I set `reportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;` as well.

Answer (score 5):

The image url must be using format `file:////F:\111\333.JPG`

Answer (score 1):

Your paths in an RDLC have to be URIs, then the string you pass to the ReportParameter is the AbsolutePath (in your case **file:///C:/Test/579569.png**)

```
    Dim filepath As Uri
    filepath = New Uri("C:\Test\579569.png")

    Dim Path As ReportParameter
    Path = New ReportParameter("Path", filepath.AbsolutePath)

    Me.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(New ReportParameter() {Path})
```

Excuse VB.Net code but you get the idea.

Comment: Actually, instead of filepath.AbsolutePath, you shoud use filepath.AbsoluteUri (at least for the latest report viewer)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting MIME Type property to ImageControl in the rdlc file?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you take a new Form in your project on Load event you Wright this line below:

```
reportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
```

after that  take reportViewer on that page and set smart tag of that, choose Design a new report and take an image control on it from ToolBox, set its property

> Source = External
>
> Value = file:\D:Images\Sunset.jpg

**Note:**  Image(Sunset.jpg) saved in Images folder on D drive. You changed it according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I got results using these codes in my own project

```
var imagePath = new Uri(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("PATH")).AbsoluteUri;
lr.ReportPath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/Report/Test1.rdlc");
lr.EnableExternalImages = true;
lr.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { 
    new ReportParameter("Path", imagePath)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is for an old post but it is still relevant now.
I searched so much and most answers are for web sites.
I was searching for c# reportviewer in a form and a local picture file.

It worked well using this:

Add the image in rdlc.
set source to external
set the value to    File:\C:\MyPics\logo.png

if the path is stored in database,
set the value to    ="File:" +First(Fields!LogoFile.Value, "DataSet1")

I also added this code in my form (you can set it directly in reportviewer control's properties if you prefer)
reportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;