# The enable externalimages property has not been set for this report?

Tags: c#, reporting, rdlc

I am trying to add an external photo as the logo along with the report on the `report.rdlc` file. I have this error

> The enable externalimages property has not been set for this report

[image]?

Here is my code.

```
 try
{
    this.pedidosTableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = con.MysqlConnect();

    this.pedidosTableAdapter.Fill(this.fabricacaoDataSet8.pedidos, Pages.relatorios.num);
    this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
}
catch { }

// for external image
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
ReportParameter parm = new ReportParameter();
parm=(new ReportParameter("path", @"C:\logo.jpg",true));
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parm);
this.reportViewer1.Refresh();
```

Comment: The code you posted swallows any exceptions without any notification, which could be part of the issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [External images in .rdlc data reports for winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070408/external-images-in-rdlc-data-reports-for-winforms)

Answer (score 7):

I have experience when you enable external images using Code, it works on local / development environment but while deployment on server it does not works and reports raise error:

**"The enable external images property has not been set for this report"**

In order to solve this issue, use `EnableExternalImages="true"` property in ASPX or design file where you are using ReportViewer Control and it will work perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

The problem here actually is, that you're calling `this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();` before setting `this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;`.

The order is important here.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this image is a help in your Windows Application.Activate your Reportviewer->Properties->LocalReport->EnableExternalImage and set it to True[image]

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070408/external-images-in-rdlc-data-reports-for-winforms), the path of the image must be in URL format, i.e. `@"file:///C:\logo.jpg"`

Or you can try

```
var filepath = new Uri("C:\logo.jpg");
var path = new ReportParameter("Path", filepath.AbsolutePath);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter {Path = path});
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing worked for me, But simply this worked

```
        LocalReport localReport = new LocalReport();
        localReport.ReportPath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Reports/myreport.rdlc");
        localReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
        localReport.EnableHyperlinks = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

For WinForm Applications, below code will works well.

```
string templateImage = Application_Path + @"\Images\ReportLogo.jpg";
rvRptContainer.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
rvRptContainer.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("ReportLogo", "File:\\" + templateImage));
```

For ASP.Net Applications, Do the following:

```
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;

    string imagePath = new Uri(Server.MapPath("~/images/Mudassar.jpg")).AbsoluteUri;

    ReportParameter parameter = new ReportParameter("ImagePath", imagePath);

    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameter);

    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```